# custom command in git submodule.<name>.update

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am trying to add a custom command to the `.gitmodule` file. According to documentation:

> arbitrary shell command that takes a single argument (the sha1 of the commit recorded in the superproject) is executed. When `submodule.<name>.update` is set to `!command`, the remainder after the exclamation mark is the custom command.

I tried something like the following:

```
[submodule "mysub"]
    path = mysub
    url = mysub-url
    branch = a-branch
    update = !ls   <<  a custom command is here
```

Moreover, the code in `submodule-config.c` contains this:

```
    } else if (!strcmp(item.buf, "update")) {
        if (!value)
            ret = config_error_nonbool(var);
        else if (!me->overwrite &&
             submodule->update_strategy.type != SM_UPDATE_UNSPECIFIED)
            warn_multiple_config(me->treeish_name, submodule->name,
                         "update");
        else if (parse_submodule_update_strategy(value,
             &submodule->update_strategy) < 0 ||
             submodule->update_strategy.type == SM_UPDATE_COMMAND)  //<<< bummer! is it supposed to be
            die(_("invalid value for %s"), var);
    }
```

However, all attempts to do so end up in: *fatal: invalid value for submodule...*

So, any idea what is going on with custom commands in submodule updates? Is it just an oversight which had never been tested? Am I missing something?

I use git 2.26.0

Comment: This should definitely work; see the code in `parse_submodule_update_type`, which includes the line `else if (*value == '!')` followed by `return SM_UPDATE_COMMAND;`.

Comment: exactly, but the value is checked **after** return from the function. I also figured out that adding this option to `.git/config` works. So, i think that this was done intentionally, but not explained in documentaion nor in the error message.

Comment: I just checked git logs. The line in the code was added by `e904deb89d9 (Jonathan Nieder      2019-12-05 01:28:28 -0800 498)                         submodule->update_strategy.type == SM_UPDATE_COMMAND)` so it was intentional: `e904deb89d - submodule: reject submodule.update = !command in .gitmodules (1 year, 1 month ago) <Jonathan Nieder>`. This happened sometime after 2.14.6.

Comment: Aha - right, I was thinking of the one in `.git/config`, which should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some digging I now think that this behavior was intentional, but it had not been reflected in documentation nor in the error message.

As a matter of fact, it works if configured in `.git/config`.

The reasoning could be: "passing around pointers to a custom command via clone can end up with inaccessible path to the custom command. So, .gitmodules could only contain predefined keywords. Otherwise, `.git/config` could be used to have it configured in a local config.". I do not necessarily agree with this. It all depends on the intention of the project.

Anyway, git blame shows this line:

```
e904deb89d9 (Jonathan Nieder      2019-12-05 01:28:28 -0800 498)                         submodule->update_strategy.type == SM_UPDATE_COMMAND)
```

and the log log for the commit:

```
 e904deb89d - submodule: reject submodule.update = !command in .gitmodules (1 year, 1 month ago) <Jonathan Nieder>
*   d3ac8c3f27 - Sync with 2.14.6 (1 year, 1 month ago) <Johannes Schindelin>
|\  
| * 66d2a6159f - (tag: v2.14.6) Git 2.14.6 (1 year, 1 month ago) <Johannes Schindelin>
```

So, this **is** intentional and looks like it was added after 2.14.6. @torek suggested that this is due to security considerations. I agree that it makes sense.

However, it would be nice if this was spelled out in the error message and/or in documentation.

Comment: Examining the commit you found (which disables the option in `.gitmodules` but not in `.git/config`), the goal here is security. If one cloned a Git repository that included in its submodule update something that opened a security hole, and Git just ran that anyway, that would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

> However, all attempts to do so end up in: `fatal: invalid value for submodule...`

Either the Git version is too old to support that custom command option (initially in [Git v1.6.1-rc1, Q3 2008](https://github.com/git/git/commit/19a31f9c1a6b18abd8a7f20d616516afca36a6a3)

Or the command is not in your `$PATH` when you execute the `git submodule update`.

Comment: I use git 2.26 and the code is from the latest pull.

Comment: @Serge be it is the folder where the executable is (not the code, but the actual program called from submodule update) is in your $PATH?